# Saving an article from a broken collaboration

Tags: ethics, collaboration

Background: In 2022, I was introduced to a professor belonging to the UK who recommended me for getting a job at an Institute "A", in India. The professor also trying to get some collaborators in "A". Later I got a better option at institute "B" in India and I joined there. The Prof. is a well-known figure in his domain. In March 2022, He gave me some suggestions regarding a work, which I executed. In September 2022 I prepared a manuscript which may be accepted in a reputed journal. But, when I joined institute B in September, he stopped all types of communication with me. I need some advice if you faced such situations earlier:

1. How can I publish this article safely? Suppose I submit the manuscript with his name. He may complain that I am using his reputation. If I submit the article without his name, his complaint may be more critical. Now, there is no physical or virtual communication between us.
2. What should I do or not do such that the chance, if any, for future collaboration will not be harmed any more?

Comment: Do you have clear records (or memories) of what are the professor's contributions to the article and what are your contributions?  Can they be separated, to produce an article that contains only your contributions and none of his?  If not, I fear your only way to proceed might be to hope the professor gets back in touch.  (And actually, September 2022-now isn't really all that long, he might be getting round to it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible from a distance to judge whether the advice given rises to the level of deserving of authorship. But it would be either wrong or sub-optimal to make assumptions without that person's input.

I suggest that you send them a copy of your work and ask their advice on publishing. How you phrase the request depends on your analysis of of whether the balance is in favor of or against sole authorship. Also, consider the issue of future collaboration with them in your phrasing.

You can also get some advice from a local professor about how to approach it as well as the sole-authorship question. One possibility, perhaps remote, is to have a local professor serve as an intermediary in any contact. That would make "ghosting" less likely as well as getting another person informed.